# Unable to get report with Response Data_Response Header and Request header in xml format using Jmeter

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

i am running jmeter test through non-gui mode and i want to view response data, response header and request header in my Log File.

Therefore i have change the below properties in jmeter.properties file

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeader=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeader=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

But after running the Jmeter Test through command Line,it is not running and through the below error:

> Jmeter version: 5:4:3

> Java Version:1.8.0_292

```
 ./jmeter  -Jgroup1.threads=1 -Jgroup1.rampup=1 -Jgroup1.loop=1 -n -t /Users/lipsa_priyadarshini/MDE_Engage-Engage_Performance_Test/Kerg-Postgresql-Performance-Test.jmx  -l /Users/lipsa_priyadarshini/Desktop/awsmigration/JmeterTestLogs/log.xml -e -o/Users/lipsa_priyadarshini/Desktop/awsmigration/HTML/report1
Creating summariser <summary>Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
```

Note: When this output format property is commented out in properties file `#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` and by passing path of log file with .xml extension , it creates xml file but does not include response data, response body, response header even if the property is true in the file.
Therefore as per my observation we can see the data, body in log file when we will set output format file as true but its not alllowing here.

can anyone debug the issue and let me know the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html):

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples from **CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views

Which means that you won't be able to generate the dashboard from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in XML format.

so you need to remove this bit:

```
-e -o/Users/lipsa_priyadarshini/Desktop/awsmigration/HTML/report1
```

from your command line, in this case the `log.xml` will have the details you're looking for.

If you need both the ability to generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard and store headers and response data consider adding a listener, i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to your test plan and configure where and what to store:

[image]

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: As m running the Test in Virtual machine, so mostly i generate report through command line so can u tell me how to save "Simple data write " and export through command